# Allow User to Specify Date Range and Sort by Date (PYTHON)

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime, user-input

This is the .csv file:

```
description,date,amount
Car,02/06/2021,26
Desk,06/11/2020,-6
Hockey Stick,07/05/2021,-26
```

Essentially, I want to sort it by the date and allow the user to input the date they want and they obtain all the rows in the .csv file that correspond to that date (or year). How can I make it so that the user is able to dictate the specific date range and then the programme spits out those results?

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

transactionFile = open("transactions.csv", "r")

dfColumns = ["description","date","amount"]
df = pd.read_csv('transactions.csv', sep=",", index_col=0, names=dfColumns)
dfData = pd.DataFrame(df)    

df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format="%d%m%Y")

print(df)
```

I'm kinda laughing at the code because I honestly have no idea what I'm doing, if someone could please give insight or help, I'd be forever grateful. Thank you :)

Comment: Have the user input the date in a certain format, then parse it into a datetime? It's not clear what exactly you're asking...

Comment: side note, `transactionFile = open("transactions.csv", "r")` is unnecessary, it just leaves an unused file reference

Comment: I will change the tranasaction file, and to answer the first question basically the user inputs a date that they want and with that information the programme outputs the corresponding transactions to that date. The date can be given within a range. Not sure if that clears it up?